# a generic .htaccess regex to get every parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Let's say I have a domain www.stackoverflow.com
I want to write an .htaccess through which I will be table to get every parameter that is passed into URL.
For e.g.

Case 1 www.stackoverflow.com/test

Case 2 www.stackoverflow.com/test/page

Case 3 www.stackoverflow.com/test/page/anotherpage

Normally I would write it this way:

> RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$
>   index.php?param1=$1 [NC,L]

But this will only work for Case 1 above so for Case 2 and 3 I have to write two separate lines like this:

> RewriteRule
>   ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$
>   index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
>   [NC,L]
>
> RewriteRule
>   ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
>   [NC,L]

As you can see this can be problematic when parameters grow. So is there a generic regex that will work for all cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - use `.` instead of `[a-z0-9-]`, and then have your `index.php` parse the parameters for you.

Comment: You mean the following?  
**RewriteRule ^.$ index.php?param=$1 [NC,L]**  

I tried this but it is not working.

Comment: Not quite - `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?param=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Thanks it worked but I can't up vote you because I don't have enough reputation.  By the way can you tell me how can I write sentence in another line? If I am not wrong you have to give two spaces at the end of sentence and then the next sentence will start from next line but it's not happening.

Comment: If I solved your problem, just accept my answer - it's like upvoting, but better :) (and it helps people who find this later see how it was solved).